# Using the Github Api V3, how do I get all repos I have write access to?

Tags: github

/user/repos only returns repos that I own. I would like a list of all repos I have write access to. Alternatively, is it possible to get a list of starred repos or a list of repos that belong to an organization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of starred repos:
https://api.github.com/users/:user_id/starred

List of repos that belong to an organization:
https://api.github.com/orgs/:org_id/repos

List user repos (all repos, where you are owner or member):
https://api.github.com/users/:user_id/repos

However, /user/repos should also return all your repos, not just the ones you own (I just tried it). Notice the `type` query parameter you can use to filter the results: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories

Comment: Just want to add explicitly that `/users/:user_id/repos` never shows any organization's repo, even if you are a member of it.